# Error: Command failed: powershell.caption 'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, powershell, gulp, spfx

**Error: Command failed: 'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

I have installed the following:

- node – version 10.23.0
- Gulp - version  3.9.1
- gulp-cli – version  2.3.0
- yo - version 3.1.1
- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint - 1.11.0

When I am trying to create a new webpart using the command -"yo @microsoft/sharepoint" I am getting the following error

```
C:\Webpart>yo @microsoft/sharepoint
C:\Users\vkat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\execa\index.js:347
                throw err;
                ^

Error: Command failed: powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption
'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


    at makeError (C:\Users\vkat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at Function.module.exports.sync (C:\Users\vkat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
    at windowsRelease (C:\Users\vkat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\windows-release\index.js:39:19)
    at osName (C:\Users\vkat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\os-name\index.js:39:18)
    at new Insight (C:\Users\vkat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\insight\lib\index.js:37:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vkat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js:54:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
```

Can anyone let me know what can be done to resolve this error.

Comment: Try launching Powershell with absolute path.

Comment: Can u Guide me how we can do that?

Comment: Absolute and relative paths are [well-documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats).

Comment: Thank You for the Suggestion. The issue is resolved